# Solution for "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' " required

Tags: oracle, data-access, oracle12c

I am trying to connect my application to ORACLE 12c but while i run the application specific windows service, getting the below error.

Earlier I had both 11g and 12c and the issue appeared. So, I removed both of them and installed fresh 12c.

Checked the frameworks folder for the said Oracle.DataAccess File. It is there. Also checked in odp.net folder of oracle installation. File is there with correct version.

Can anyone help me out????

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

Comment: Try to copy the dll to folder of your application binaries

Comment: ... and try checking for the DLL's file access privileges. It may be that the Windows service you are referring to is runnnig under an OS user that lacks assess rights to the assembly DLL.